# PHP exec not working in another project/directory hosted on same server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to execute pdfinfo from my shared hosting. I hosted the project under **domain/demo/project_name** and everything was working fine. So once the project got finalised I moved the project to **domain/live/project_name**.

After moving the project, php exec throws null, for debugging process, heck I even gave 777 permission to all my directories & files but still no results.

I'm successfully able to run 'ls' command. I tried to run and display 'ls' and pdfinfo but the pdfinfo throws null.

My Sample Code:

```
exec("ls", $output);
var_dump($output);

echo "<br/>";

exec("$cmd \"$document\"", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

My Output:

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(10) "LICENSE.md" [1]=> string(9) "README.md" [2]=> string(11) "application" [3]=> string(5) "files" [4]=> string(9) "index.php" [5]=> string(6) "public" [6]=> string(6) "system" }

array(7) { [0]=> string(10) "LICENSE.md" [1]=> string(9) "README.md" [2]=> string(11) "application" [3]=> string(5) "files" [4]=> string(9) "index.php" [5]=> string(6) "public" [6]=> string(6) "system" }
```

Turns out my second exec is not at all executed. The same exec runs properly when I run on **domain/demo/project_name**

Things I have double-checked

- Permissions
- Command Path
- Document Path

**What must be the issue?**

Comment: Have you checked server permissions ? actually, I'd say that exec command on shared hosting would *not* be allowed

Comment: Hi @OldPadawan as I said, I'm able to run exec under my demo directory(same hosting server) but not working under another directory, I did double check the permissions and 'ls' command is working perfectly.